# Is $X$ with moment generating function such that $\psi_X(1)=2$ and $\psi_X(2)=4$ constant?

Tags: probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

I came across the following claim that puzzles me:

> Suppose that $X$ is a random variable with moment generating function $\psi_X$ such that $\psi_X(1) = 2$ and $\psi_X(2) = 4$. Show that $\boldsymbol{\mathrm e}^{X}$ is constant.

First since $t \mapsto \boldsymbol{\mathrm e}^t$ is strictly increasing it should be sufficient to show that $X$ is almost surely constant?

Now from the given information, and the definition of the moment generating function, we have that
$$
\int 2 \boldsymbol{\mathrm e}^X dp = \int \boldsymbol{\mathrm e}^{2X} dp .
$$

> If $X$ has a point mass at $\ln 2$ then the equation is true. Now I wonder if this really is the only possibility?

The equation 
$$
2 \boldsymbol{\mathrm e}^t = \boldsymbol{\mathrm e}^{2t}
$$
has the single solution $\ln 2$ and
\begin{align*}
2 \boldsymbol{\mathrm e}^t > \boldsymbol{\mathrm e}^{2t} &\text{ if } t < \ln 2 \\
2 \boldsymbol{\mathrm e}^t < \boldsymbol{\mathrm e}^{2t} &\text{ if } \ln 2 < t.
\end{align*}
What if we take $X$ to have a two point mass, one point to the left and one point to the right of $\ln 2$, of equal probability? Isn't it possible to pick one point to the left where $2 \boldsymbol{\mathrm e}^t - \boldsymbol{\mathrm e}^{2t} = x$ and one point to the right where $\boldsymbol{\mathrm e}^{2t} - 2 \boldsymbol{\mathrm e}^t = x$ and assign $X$ to have equal probability on them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show that variance of $e^X$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

As per StubbornAtom's comment: From the known formula, that for any random variable $Z$, 
$$
\mathrm{E}\left[\left(Z- \mathrm WE[Z]\right)^2 \right ] = \mathrm E\left [Z^2 \right] - \mathrm E \left[Z \right]^2,
$$
it follows that 
$$
\mathrm{E}\left [\left(e^X - \mathrm E[e^X] \right)^2\right]= \mathrm E\left[e^{2X}\right] - \mathrm E\left [e^X\right]^2 = \psi(2) - \psi(1)^2 = 0.
$$
This means that, almost surely, $e^X$ equals $\mathrm E\left[e^{2X}\right] $. In other words $e^X$ is almost surely constant. This contradicts what I have written in my post. But I'm not sure what is at fault with my original argument.